# How to get image url by cheerio?

Tags: node.js, image, cheerio

[image]I want to get image urls by **scraping** data by cheerio from a slider but can able to do this tried a lot but can found a solution here is my code below

```
const retURL = a.find('.gallery-carousel').find('img').attr('src')
.map(function(){ 
    let image=  $(this).attr('src'); 
    console.log(image, 'nnnnknknkn')
 })
 const retURL = $('div.carousel').attr('img')
 const retURL = $('gallery-carousel__image-touchable').text()
```

Comment: did you get a solution for your issue?

Comment: @JayakumarThangavel not at all

Comment: can you please add HTML code also

Comment: @JayakumarThangavel which html code i have added inspect elements and code

Comment: var imageurl = $('.gallery-carousel__image-touchable').find('img').attr('src');

Comment: var imageurl = $('.slide button').find('img').attr('src');

Comment: @JayakumarThangavel failed , return undefined

Comment: @JayakumarThangavel should we use map function ?

Comment: Map function used when an array of result set but in this case, there is string return type so I believe it's not required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202192/discussion-between-hammad-ul-hasan-and-jayakumar-thangavel).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var listItems = $(".gallery-carousel ul li");
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    let image=  $(li).find('img').attr('src'); 
    console.log(image);
    // and the rest of your code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-carousel">
<ul>
<li class="slide selected">
<button><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC97H.png" alt="hello" /> </button>
</li>
<li class="slide">
<button><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1.png" alt="hello" /> </button>
</li>
<li class="slide">
<button><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2.png" alt="hello" /> </button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```