# Cherrio JS return all image SRCs of parent div

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

Consider the following HTML:

```html
<div aria-roledescription="carousel" data-disliderguid="slider772" class="di-slider slider772-slider gmus-1800x760-slider">
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<div
   class="di-slide swiper-slide"
   data-guid="slide2221"
   data-screen="desktop"
   data-title="995_2024_All_Hummer_Evergreen_2024_DWC"
   data-id="2221"
   data-filtervalue=""
   data-swiper-autoplay="3000">
   
   <div class="di-slider-disclaimer">
      <button class="di-slider-disclaimer-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="inactive-label">Important Information</span>
      <span class="active-label">Hide Information</span>
      </button>
      <div class="di-slider-disclaimer-container">
         <div class="di-slider-disclaimer-contents">
            Preproduction and simulated models shown throughout. Actual production model may vary. HUMMER EV is available from a GMC EV dealer.                                
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="di-slider-link"
      aria-hidden="true"
      href="/new-vehicles/?_dFR%5Byear%5D%5B0%5D=2024&_dFR%5Bmake%5D%5B0%5D=GMC&_dFR%5Bmodel%5D%5B0%5D=HUMMER+EV&_dFR%5Bmodel%5D%5B1%5D=HUMMER+EV+SUV&_dFR%5Bmodel%5D%5B2%5D=HUMMER+EV+Pickup"
      title=""
      tabindex="-1"
      >
      <picture class="slide-image">
         <source media="(max-width: 767px)"                                     srcset="https://gtmassets.dealerinspire.com/9061-995_2024_All_Hummer_Evergreen_2024_DWC_600x400.jpg">
         <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
            srcset="https://gtmassets.dealerinspire.com/9061-995_2024_All_Hummer_Evergreen_2024_DWC_1800x760.jpg">
         <img src="https://gtmassets.dealerinspire.com/9061-995_2024_All_Hummer_Evergreen_2024_DWC_1800x760.jpg"                                      alt="GMC HUMMER EV PICKUP AND SUV"
            style=""
            width="1800" height="760">
      </picture>
   </a>
</div>
<div
   class="di-slide swiper-slide"
   data-guid="slide950"
   data-screen="desktop"
   data-title="Generic"
   data-id="950"
   data-filtervalue=""
   >
<picture class="slide-image">
   <source media="(max-width: 767px)"                                     srcset="https://di-uploads-development.dealerinspire.com/robertsonsgmc-winback0123/uploads/2023/03/Group-of-2023-GMC-Terrain-SUVs-parked-on-beach_mobile.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
      srcset="https://di-uploads-development.dealerinspire.com/robertsonsgmc-winback0123/uploads/2023/03/Group-of-2023-GMC-Terrain-SUVs-parked-on-beach-1800x760.jpg">
   <img src="https://di-uploads-development.dealerinspire.com/robertsonsgmc-winback0123/uploads/2023/03/Group-of-2023-GMC-Terrain-SUVs-parked-on-beach-1800x760.jpg"                                      alt="Group of 2023 GMC Terrain SUVs parked on beach"
      style="visibility:hidden"
      width="1800" height="760">
</picture>
```

I am trying to use Cheerio via ScrapeNinja to return the SRC of all images that are children of the Div class di-slider, as seen in the first line of the HTML snippet. All images are of the HTML picture object, and all have a similar div class. However, the only link I want returned is the  value.

When I try to run the following code on their sandbox: https://scrapeninja.net/cheerio-sandbox/basic, I get an error "Error: Expected name, found ://gtmassets.dealerinspire.com/9061-995_2024_All_Hummer_Evergreen_2024_DWC_1800x760.jpg on line 19"

Here is the error I'm getting:

```js
// define function which accepts body and cheerio as args
function extract(input, cheerio) {
    // return object with extracted values              
    let $ = cheerio.load(input);
    var listItems = $(".di-slider");
    listItems.each(function(idx, picture) {
    let image= $(picture).find('img').attr('src'); 
    return {
        source: $(image)
    };
});
    
}
```

I admit, I am not the greatest with JS, I haven't used jQuery in years, and this is my first time trying to use cheerio or scrapeninja.

I have reviewed documentation at https://pixeljets.com/blog/cheerio-sandbox-cheatsheet/#iterate-over-children-and-return-them-as-an-array-of-objects, and I built my function off of [How to get image url by cheerio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802966/how-to-get-image-url-by-cheerio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

1. The main reason for the crash is that you're putting a string into a Cheerio object: `$("https://gtmassets.dealerinspire.com...")`. Remove the `$()` here.
2. `.forEach`/`.each` doesn't return a value. Anything you return from it is ignored. `.map`, on the other hand, allocates an array using all of the values returned by your callback. This is the best function for the job. You could also push each item onto an array variable, but that's the express purpose of the `map` abstraction.
3. You need to return something from `extract()`. [Formatting your code](https://prettier.io/playground/) may make it easier to notice this.

Working code:

```js
function extract(input, cheerio) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(input);
  return [...$(".di-slider")].map(e => ({
    source: $(e).find("img").attr("src")
  }));
}
```

To get all of the `src` attributes for all images inside each slider, you can use a nested map:

```js
function extract(input, cheerio) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(input);
  return [...$(".di-slider")].map(e => ({
    sources: [...$(e).find("img")].map(e => $(e).attr("src"))
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that part of this ggorlen! While this does get me the first SRC, how can I modify your function to return all the SRCs in that snippet? They are all children of the di-slider class, in the above snippet, I included 2 images

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. You can map over the `img`s using the same strategy as the sliders: `sources: [...$(e).find("img")].map(e => $(e).attr("src"))`.

Comment: Thank you so much again! I have included the full function in the OP for anyone else that needs it!

Comment: Thanks for that, but generally we don't edit the answer into the question--it's important to see the context only in the question so the fix is clear to future visitors. Also, new answers may come along that are better than this, or the Cheerio API changes, and if this answer is specifically baked into the question, it gives too much priority/authority to it. Votes will determine which is the best. See [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question).

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware!